# How to assign Two segues on a table cell in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I am totally new at IOS swift and working with android.

Here is my issue :

I'm developing a simple chatting App of IOS. I've already completed android ver and this is a kind of clone.

It has view controllers named VCList, VCMyFriends and VCChat. VCList is my very first view controller and has a table view. Touching a table view cell changes current view controller to VCMyFriends or VCChat.

When I touch a cell, app checks the member counts of the cell, so if it has other members then go to VCChat. If not, VCMyFriends on to invite my friends. Like following pic.

[image]

What I found is, I cannot assign two segues on a cell or split a segue with two ways. So I thought that can I change my VC without a segue? However I could not find any references or tutorial about it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if( memberCnt == 0 ) {
        self.presentViewController(VCMyFriends(), animated: true, completion: nil);
    } else {
        self.presentViewController(VCChat(), animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}
```

Above is my last try, and failed. It moves somewhere, but shows nothing at all. And if I can, I wish to use segues because have some datas to pass with segue.

Take care.

Comment: You are right to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but you should use `performSegueWithIdentifier` rather than `presentViewController`.  You can set the segue identifier in storyboard and link the segue from the orange view controller icon at the top of the scene

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is to create an instance of the controller via the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and set the necessary member variables before calling presentViewController.  You can also add a NavigationController if you want the capability the go back to the previous window.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let mainStoryBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if( memberCnt == 0 )
    {
      let vcMyFriends = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCMyFriend") as! VCMyFriends
      vcMyFriends.membervar1 = membervar1
      vcMyFriends.membervar2 = membervar2

      self.presentViewController(vcMyFriends, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
      let vcChat = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCChat") as! VCChat
      vcChat.membervar1 = membervar1
      vcChat.membervar2 = membervar2

      self.presentViewController(vcChat, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

*membervar* and *membervar2* are the data that you pass to the View Controllers.  You need to set it before calling presentViewController so that they will be available when viewDidLoad is called.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if( memberCnt == 0 ) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("VCMyFriends_segue", sender: self)
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("VCChat_segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

In your storyboard, select the first `segue` (*the red line in your image*) and choose `Attributes inspector`, then add **VCMyFriends_segue** as identifier.

Do the same thing for the second line (*blue*) and add **VCChat_segue** identifier.

Hope this helps